# AWS AppSync Versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, versioning, aws-appsync

I have set up an AWS AppSync including a GraphQL Schema, corresponding data sources as Dynamo DB tables as well as S3 Buckets from which I read data into the tables employing lambda functions.

I would like to version this setup by means of VCS (ideally, GitHub), such that I can set up a staging and production environment. I have not come across a simple way of doing so, except for simply "copy pasting" everything from one env to the other. Anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible to manage AWS AppSync configuration as code. In fact, we highly recommend it as the model to follow!

CloudFormation has full support for AWS AppSync capabilities. You can model your schema, resolvers, and data sources in CloudFormation, commit the file(s) to source control, and perform repeated deployments using continuous deployment practices.

We’ve published a detailed walkthrough that shows how you can [manage and deploy an AWS AppSync GraphQL API with CloudFormation](https://adrianhall.github.io/cloud/2018/04/17/deploy-an-aws-appsync-graphql-api-with-cloudformation/).

Comment: Walkthrough link is now broken.

Comment: This article looks to be covering the same ground -> https://adrianhall.github.io/cloud/2018/04/17/deploy-an-aws-appsync-graphql-api-with-cloudformation/

Comment: Yep, that's the article. Adrian had written it and published to acloudguru and his blog. Thanks for finding it @BernardNandwa. Updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

We've have been using Serverless Framework and serverless-appsync-plugin with great success.

Serverless (https://github.com/serverless/serverless) supports staging and it uses CloudFormation under the hood. You can think of it as a nice wrapper for managing and building your CloudFormation deployments.

serverless-appsync-plugin (https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin) is a Serverless plugin that helps you to write AppSync CloudFormation deployments without clutter.

Perhaps the answers for this question are also helpful: [How to develop serverless as a team with AWS AppSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50560118/1207523)